# Is there software for windows that works like Guake?

Tags: windows, terminal

I'm looking for something similiar to Guake, but for windows. I'd like to have an ability to connect via SSH to my virtual linux machine and show/hide the terminal using 1 hotkey.

Comment: Hi, this question is unfairly closed. It is on topic question. I'm developer and I use the guake style console on Linux and on Windows systems. This question should be reopened, as it's on demand topic for Developers worked on both systems.

Comment: I would love to see some more discussion on this. True, not exactly a programming question but managing consoles is very closely related to to many programming tasks. I could go on a rant about other aspects of why I hate working with the windows command prompt.

Comment: // , Good question, but isn't it more of a software recommendation? I don't think it's unfairly closed, at all, but it is a question I'm really interested in! I hate Winblow$ with the fiery passion of the damned, but in those brief, resume-updating periods that I'm forced to use it, this is definitely on my mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try out these

[Guake with putty](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/78098-windows-guake-like-putty-session/)

Personally, i like to keep the terminal open on another workspace, i do that in windows using windows pager
[Windows pager](http://windowspager.sourceforge.net/)

Using

```
ctrl + win key + left arrow/right arrow
```

you can shift to the workspace you want with the terminal